# Как задать промежуток для DatePicker WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

У меня есть `DatePicker` и я хочу установить для него стартовую и конечную дату по следующим правилам:

1. Стартовая дата: Текущая дата минус 3 дня
2. Конечная дата: Текущая дата

Хочу сделать это только средствами XAML. Пока что только получается забиндить на текущую дату, но не получается отнять три дня для формирования промежутка

```
<xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib;"
...
<DatePicker 
           DisplayDateStart="Тут надо что-то типа DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)" 
           DisplayDateEnd="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, Path=.}">
</DatePicker>
```

Comment: Сделайте простой конвертор, который на вход будет получать дату и значение, на сколько надо эту дату изменить.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ забиндить DateTime.Now, но конвертер будет изменять значение на нужный мне диапазон?

Comment: Не диапазон, а именно `DisplayDateStart="Тут надо что-то типа DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3)"`, вот это без проблем можно сделать конвертором. Можете пойти другим путем и написать свое поведение, которое через attached property будет задано `DataPicker`'у.